# Simple question concerning the properties of the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

I need to prove that every element of the fundamental group has an inverse.

First we define a map $\phi:I\to I$ homotopic to $\operatorname{Id}_I$. If $\phi$ is the constant zero function isn't it true that $f\circ \phi \simeq f$? So if we denote the inverse of $f$ by $f'$ isn't it true that $(f\ast f')\circ \phi \simeq f\ast f'$ and $(f\ast f')\circ \phi = e$, which means $e\simeq f\ast f'$? ($\ast$ is the product of paths and $e$ is the identity element)

But the problem is that I didn't use any property of the inverse element, so something is wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is $f$ a map $I\to X$ with $f(0)=f(1)=x_0, x_0$ some basepoint? If so, then no, $f\circ\phi$ certainly need not be homotopic to $f$. For instance, consider $X$ the circle and $f(t)=e^{2i\pi t}$.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect. $f\circ\phi$ is not in general homotopic to $f$- it's homotopic to  the constant map taking the value $f(0)$.

To prove that every element of the fundamental group has an inverse, think about some examples of elements of the fundamental group and their inverses. You should see a pattern jumping out that suggests a natural course for your proof.

Comment: Yes, $f\circ \phi$ is homotopic to the constant map but $\phi$ is homotopic to the identity. So isn't it true that $f\circ \phi \simeq f\circ \operatorname{Id}=f$?

Comment: Yes, but $\phi$ is not homotopic to $Id_I$ relative to the endpoints of the interval. Recall that elements of $\pi_1(X,x)$ are loops based at $x$, so when representing them as paths, we need to consider them up to homotopy relative to the endpoints.

Comment: I believe the emphasis on the fundamental **group** rather than **groupoid** leads to confusion for students. If a path is thought of as a "journey"  then the opposite $-f$ of a path from $x$ to $y$ is clearly a path from $y$ to $x$.  Of course to get an exact inverse you have to take homotopy classes rel end points,  but the choice of a single base point obscures the geometry.